# Find $\lim_{z \rightarrow -1+i} (z-(-1+i))\frac{e^{zt}}{z^{2}(z^{2}+2z+2)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I find this limit?

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow -1+i} z-(-1+i)\frac{e^{zt}}{z^{2}(z^{2}+2z+2)}$$

My textbook's answer is $\frac{e^{(-1+i)t}}{4}$. But when I try to solve it my result comes out zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : $$z^2+2z+2=(z+1-i)(z+1+i)$$

Comment: O my God..I  wasted 1 hour on this..I didn't try to fractorize...thank you so much sir